# Angular2: displaying items in row/column fashion

Tags: css, angular, angularjs-directive, angular2-template

I have an array with the below format, where first parameter is the text to be displayed, second is the column number and third is the row number. I want to display these items based on their column and row location.

```
[[ "a",  "0", "0"],
["b", "0", "1"],
["c", "0", "2"],
["d", "1", "0"],
["e", "1", "1"],
["f", "2", "0"],
["g", "2", "1"]
```

]

Desired Output:

```
a d f
b e g
c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this : **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WMDXvyR7XS57ABSqE7Sc?p=preview)**

Component :

```
  value : string;
  rows : any[];
  cols : any[];
  arr : any = [[ "a",  "0", "0"],
    ["b", "0", "1"],
    ["c", "0", "2"],
    ["d", "1", "0"],
    ["e", "1", "1"],
    ["f", "2", "0"],
    ["g", "2", "1"]];

  constructor() { 
    this.rows = Array(3).fill();
    this.cols = Array(3).fill();
  }

  activeElement(r,c) : string{
    for(let elem of this.arr){
      if(parseInt(elem[1]) === c && parseInt(elem[2]) === r){
        console.log(true);
        return elem[0];
      }
    }
    return ""
  }
```

Template :

```
<div *ngFor="let row of rows; let rowId = index">
 <span *ngFor="let col of cols; let colId = index">
   {{activeElement(rowId,colId)}}
 </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Here I think you are assuming the number of rows and columns.

Comment: Indeed. You can still, loop to try to find the larger col / row number in the array and use it in the constructor.

Comment: Here if I want to use bootstrap to display these items, like "col-md- 4" for 3 column grid, "col-md-6" for 2 column, "col-md-12" for 1 column grid how can I achieve this dynamically, once I know the number of columns value. Here if I want to use bootstrap to display these items, like "col-md- 4" for 3 column grid, "col-md-6" for 2 column, "col-md-12" for 1 column grid how can I achieve this dynamically, once I know the number of columns value.

Comment: YounesM: Here if I want to use bootstrap to display these items, like "col-md- 4" for 3 column grid, "col-md-6" for 2 column, "col-md-12" for 1 column grid how can I achieve this dynamically, once I know the number of columns value.

Comment: @indra257 : You can use `ngClass`. `<div [ngClass]="{'col-md-4' : colNumber === 3, 'col-md-6' : colNumber === 2}">`

Comment: Actually here a,b,c,d .. are my component names. At present I am using a *NgFor to loop through my array and use switch case to call each component. But as I want to display them in row/column fashion, I tried the above approach. Now I want to club both of them. Here instead of {{activeElement}}, I should use switch case and call the required component.

Comment: Any chance to look in to the above comment?

Comment: You should post a new question since it has nothing to do with the original question and post what you've tried. I can't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071686/angular2-displaying-components-in-row-column-fashion

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at flex box [Flex Box](http://cssreference.io/flexbox/).

Essentially you will want to use a column based layout that wraps.

Additionally, there is a component library for Angular to declarative help with this: [FlexLayout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)

Using FlexLayout you would do something like this:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div fxFlexLayout="column" fxLayoutWrap>
      <div fxFlex="30%" *ngFor="let item of items | async">{{ item }}</div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ItemListComponent implements OnInit {

    items: Observable<Item[]>

    constructor(...) {}

    ngOnInit() {
       this.items = this.service.getItems()
         .map(x => x.[0])
    }

}
```

Comment: I think (s)he don't want to use CSS but populate a html grid depending on the ids on the array.