# Angular2: Displaying components in row/column fashion

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have an array with the below structure where the first field is the component name, second is the data for that component, third is column number and fourth is row number.

I am planning to display these items based on their col and row location.

```
[
    {"PieChart", Piechartdata, 0,1},
    {"donut", donutdata, 1,0},
    {"grid", griddata, 1,1}
]
```

I tried to use `*ngFor` and loop through these array and use switch case to call the desired component. But all these components are displayed one below the other. But I want to display them based on their `col, row` location

```
 <table *ngFor="let Component of gadgetsComponents">
     <div  [ngSwitch]=Component[0]>
         <div *ngSwitchCase="'PieChart'">
             <app-donut [donutchartData] = "Component[1]"> </app-donut> 
         </div>
         <div *ngSwitchCase="'grid'"> 
             <app-grid [gridData] = "gadgetsComponent[1]"> </app-grid>
         </div>
```

Comment: You array is neither a JSON neither an array...

Comment: I don't know whether I am doing the right approach or not. I have some components, their data, their column and row location and I want to display them on my page. I tried the above approach and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are use `table` why not taking advantage of it ?

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QolvdlPx7E6zyYoEGQZj?p=preview)**

```
<table>
 <tr *ngFor="let row of rows; let rowId = index">
 <td *ngFor="let col of cols; let colId = index">
   <div *ngIf="activeElement(rowId,colId) === 'PieChart'">PichartComponent</div>
   <div *ngIf="activeElement(rowId,colId) === 'donut'">DonutComponent</div>
   <div *ngIf="activeElement(rowId,colId) === 'grid'">GridComponent</div>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to use bootstrap's 'col-md-*' so that it looks more structured instead of table?

Comment: But here we should be able to pass the data "Piechartdata" while calling the PieChartComponent. From activeElement(rowId,colId) we are getting the chart type only.

Comment: I got a different idea, how about adding anchor points and enabling/disabling them based on the number of columns.